# Elasticsearch NEST - adding a SHOULD term dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm building up a series of filters dynamically using the operator overloading syntax.

```
MainQuery &= QueryContainer1;
MainQuery &= QueryContainer2;
etc.
```

Some of the filters are optional so I want them to only boost the results if found. I essentially want this:

```
bool
|___must
|   |___term
|   |___term
|
|___filter
|   |___term
|
|___should
   |___term
   |___term
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to achieve this with overloading syntax. It actually says here in the documentation that this won't produce the above result because it expects at least one of the "Should Terms" to match.

```
MustTerm1 && Filter1 && (ShouldTerm1 || ShouldTerm2)
```

The documentation:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html#_combining_queries_with_or_should_clauses

What I actually want to do is this:

```
MustTerm1 && Filter1 && (optionally)ShouldTerm1 && (optionally)ShouldTerm2
```

Or if it can't be done in this syntax is there any other way to add "Should" filters to my Querycontainer while I'm building it up?

Comment: You can build a `bool` query and pass a collection of queries as `must`, `should` and `filter` clauses: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-query-usage.html

Comment: Ah yes. That makes more sense. Thanks, @Russ-Cam.

Comment: No problem, happy to help :) Note that the fluent API accept multiple lambda expressions for each of the clauses.